# Vector/Tensor analysis, Elastic Waves

Tags: physics, vector-analysis

So I'm fairly confused at the moment.

For reference, I'm reading [this document](http://www.uab.ro/auajournal/upload/15_84_Ion_Craciun_ictami_nou.pdf), and the current area of interest is **Section 7: Characteristic Surfaces for Planar Waves**.

I'm not gonna give too much context because I'm pretty sure this is just a math problem. **I could be wrong**

I'm attaching a [;\LaTeX;] document of my own because writing it up in here is a pain.

[Here is the my attached writeup](https://cloudup.com/ce79EW8IAkj) (Please let me know if you cannot view this document) (This is also now a complete description of what I did)

Thanks, and let me know if you have any additional questions, I almost certainly left something important out.

Comment: Well, even though your making us jump through hoops to answer your question, you did provide good references and context. +1

Comment: Please I have no interest in making you jump through hoops, don't hesitate to request clarification, and I'll even provide a complete write-up of my solution in a minute. Let me put it together.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my language was to strong, you're fine, the hoop was waiting 5 seconds for a page to load. Not a big deal, although you should learn the formatting here.

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry I don't know I suck at stack exchange. I just changed my writeup, which is a more complete description of my arithmetic. It seems spot on, I'm super confused

Comment: what?? I didn't say that. I think you should learn formatting, that doesn't mean now, it means learn it within about a week or so...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't trying to accuse you or anything, I'm not totally sure how I should format it properly, though. 

Any ideas on my problem?